# Fetching data return [object Object] in my React Native app instead of the renderSectionHeader

Tags: react-native, sqlite, expo, fetch-api

I encountered a problem while trying to fetch data from an API URL, the problem is that the data are not returning by the category title in the SectionList instead I have the data returning under the title  `[object Object]` instead of the `renderSectionHeader`.

My issue reproduction Snack Expo:
https://snack.expo.dev/@fyardlest/resto-app?platform=android

[image]

Comment: Instead of putting tons of codes, you could put your fetch scenario and then make a Snack Expo reproduction. It would be much much better to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data type schema isn't matched to the [SectionList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist) requirement. Please take a look at the given link. Your data schema is like the following:

```json
[
  { category: {title: 'Appetizers'}, id: 1, price: "10", title: "Spinach Artichoke Dip" },
  ~~~
  ~~~
]
```

But the `SectionList` component expects the following:

```json
[
  {
    title: 'Main dishes',
    data: ['Pizza', 'Burger', 'Risotto'],
  },
]
```

A `SectionList` except the first array level needs one level deeper though. So I think you should use [FlatList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist).

---

However, the main issue comes from your `saveMenuItems` function:

```js
export function saveMenuItems(menuItems) {
  db.transaction((tx) => {
    const values = menuItems
      .map(
        (item) =>
          `('${item.id}', '${item.title}', '${item.price}', '${item.category}')`
      )
      .join(', ');

    tx.executeSql(
      `insert into menuitems (uuid, title, price, category) values ${values};`
    );
  });
}
```

This function makes the `category` as `[object Object]` because you used `${item.category}` which the  `item.categorty` is an object like this: `{ title: 'something' }`. And then inside `getSectionListData` the issue appears itself and makes another issue.

I think you should use `${item.category.title}` in the `saveMenuItems` function.

Comment: You make it easier for me to think about the way to retrieve the data, and I come up with another solution. Thx again for the tips. I have posted the solution below.

Answer (score 1):

I also modify the way I fetch the data and it works too. here is what I have done by setting up the category:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
try {
  const response = await fetch(API_URL);

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
  }

  const data = await response.json();

  // here is the way I retrieve the category title

  menuItems = data.menu.map((item) => ({
    ...item,
    category: item.category.title
  }))

  return menuItems
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
  return [];
}

};
```